# Byobu shift-arrow key shortcut

Tags: kubuntu, shortcut-keys, kde, byobu

After using GNU screen for years I have recently started to use Byobu. The `F shortcuts` are a bit far for my my liking so I want to use `shift/alt - arrow keys`. `Alt-left/right arrow` works find for switching between windows, and `Alt-up/down arrow` works fine for sessions switching, however `Shift-left/right/up/down arrow` do nothing except scroll the konsole (I am using KDE so Kubuntu). I am sure they probably work when only in a terminal, for example, when I SSH in via putty however when at my PC locally they scroll. My guess was that these shortcuts are set globally somewhere by something else, but I have searched everywhere and can not find any shortcuts to disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Konsole doesn't work with some (many?) of [Byobu's](http://byobu.co) key bindings.  It seems that Konsole "eats" some of these key presses, unfortunately.  While many terminals work to some degree with Byobu, the best experience will be found with gnome-terminal.

*Full disclosure: I am the author and maintainer of [Byobu](http://byobu.co).*

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave it here for the people who are struggling with this problem.

1. Settings -> Configure Keyboard shortcuts: search for any shortcut with Shift+up/down/left/right and undefine it.
2. Settings -> Configure Konsole -> Profiles -> New. In new window in Keyboard select Default (Xfree 4) and click edit. Define four new records showed on screenshot:
   [keycodes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WRCxV.png)
3. Make this profile default then restart Konsole. Now it should work.
4. Optional: if it is not working - try to search another shortcuts defined globally in system.